# Неспособность к изучению

Tags: python, информация

занимаюсь программированием чуть менее года(да я знаю ужасно мало), меня часто мучает вопрос, о том как развиваются другие программисты. Дело в том, что технические документации очень сложно даются для понимания, например библиотека  socket (https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) совершенно не понятная. приходится учиться по гайдам, книгам, видео. Но это же не может продолжаться вечно, когда-нибудь настанет день, что единственный источник информации окажется документация в которой я ничего не смыслю. Подскажите это я не могу ничего понять без хорошего объяснения, или большинство тоже? Если только я, то с чем это может быть связано? Как грамотно искать информацию по нужному инструменту? Как учились вы?

Comment: Первый источник это stackoverflow.com :) А дальше уже если надо что-то подробнее узнать о функции или чем-то другом стоит смотреть документацию (тем более, что ответы могут быть устаревшимы)

Comment: так мило. вы уже поняли, что документация - лучший источник информации о технологии, но не можете в это поверить :)

Comment: Это нормально. Как правило хорошая документация еще содержит помимо описания, еще и примеры использования, на которых можно разобрать принцип её работы. По вашей ссылке, к примеру, это будет в самом конце в секции Example. А если там только голое описание без примеров, то приходится страдать, смотреть другие источники и подключать опыт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У новичков ситуация вроде "Ммм, блин, сложная документация, пойду посмотрю видео" - это совершенно нормально. Не нужно воспринимать документацию как единственно верный источник информации. В документациях часто любят дать непрактичные примеры, лишь бы показать мощь своего инструмента. Изучайте информацию так, как нравится вам. Используйте документацию лишь для устранения недопонимания конкретных случаев. Например, нужно уточнить - каким методом нужно воспользоваться, чтобы сделать n-ое действие.
В остальном могу просто пожелать удачи и не бросать начатое.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте делать какие-то проекты с применением инструмента, который вам нужен. Так вы изучите его на практике и сделаете себе портфолио

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от конкретной документации. Чтобы понимать документацию по сокетам в питоне, надо для начала понимать что такое сокеты в принципе: bind, accept и прочую классику. Тогда будет понятно, что ожидать от питоновского API. Если же непонятна документация по `list` или `map`, но при этом есть понимание этих структур данных, то это уже странно, да.